# How to show a geoTiff on an iOS application?

Tags: gps, geotiff-tiff, ios

I'm developing an iOS application that will use offline maps. These maps are on GeoTiff format but I don't know how to do it.

I've found this question: [How to display a GeoTIFF on mapView](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/43274-How-to-display-a-GeoTIFF-on-mapView) but it uses **ARCGis** and I don't have a license to use it.

Is there any other way to show a GeoTiff? And, of course, use GPS to show where user is.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier if you can convert geotiff to tiles using GDAL (gdal2tiles utility), then to a mbtiles package, and then use offline tile viewer tool like [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk):

```
gdal2tiles.py -r cubic --s_srs EPSG:900913 mygeotiff.tif mytiles
mb-util --scheme=osm mytiles/ mytileset.mbtiles
```

If you really need to read geotiff directly, then I would use same GDAL library (libgdal) which is crossplatform and can be compiled to iOs. See [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643898/incorporating-gdal-ogr-into-an-ios-project-a-quick-guide) about it.